# C++11 backwards compatibility (conversion of null integer constant to pointer)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, language-lawyer

The C++ standard allows the implicit conversion of **zero integer constant** to pointer of any type.

The following code is invalid, because the value `v` is not constant here:

```
float* foo()
{
    int v = 0;
    return v;    // Error
}
```

But the following code is correct:

```
float* foo()
{
    const int v = 0;
    return v;    // Ok in C++98 mode, error in C++11 mode
}
```

**The question is**: why `gcc` and `clang` (tried different versions) compile the code correctly in c++98/03 mode but return warning/error when compiled in c++11/14 mode (`-std=c++11`)? I tried to find the changes in C++11 working draft PDF, but got no success.

Intel compiler 16.0 and VS2015 compilers show no errors and warnings in both cases.

Comment: Maybe they implemented those warnings while implementing `nullptr` and `std::nullptr_t`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GCC and Clang behave differently with `-std=c++11` because C++11 changed the definition of a null pointer constant, and then C++14 changed it again, see Core [DR 903](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#903) which changed the rules in C++14 so that only literals are null pointer constants.

In C++03 4.10 [conv.ptr] said:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

That allows all sorts of of expressions, as long as they are constant and evaluate to zero. Enumerations, `false`, `(5 - 5)` etc. etc. ... this used to cause lots of problems in C++03 code.

In C++11 it says:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

And in C++14 it says:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

This is a much more restrictive rule, and makes far more sense.

Comment: I found the answer in the section "Proposed resolution (October, 2012):", paragraph 1: "A null pointer constant is an **integer literal** (2.13.2 [lex.icon]) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.".

Comment: I see. But even g++ 4.7 (the first version that supports -std=c++11) shows an error. clang: 3.0 -> ok, 3.2, 3.3 -> warning, 3.4+ -> error. Seems the compilers apply the C++14 rules in C++11 mode.

Comment: Looking at your C++03 quote, wasn't `v` already not an rvalue in that standard? I may be misreading, but I'm not seeing the difference between C++03 and C++11. Is there some part of the standard that says the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion gets applied in C++03 before the expression gets considered as a null pointer constant, and it gets applied in C++11 only afterwards? Or am I just missing the point? (Agreed by the way that the C++14 rule makes sense. :))

Comment: @AndreyNasonov, DR 903 is "DR" status, meaning it is considered a bug fix for the published standard not just a change to be made in the next standard. Typically compilers apply DRs for older language dialects, as you see in this case.

Comment: @hvd, I'm not sure, there might have been a change the the definition of integral constant expression that made a difference, but I'm just guessing (I haven't tried to find the reasons).

Comment: @JonathanWakely Heh, looking at GCC's bug about it ([PR52145](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52145) -- by your own comment there), and at GCC's source code (`gcc/cp/call.c`, specifically the `null_ptr_cst_p` function), I guess there really isn't any difference between the C++03 and the C++11 wording, it's just that the DR is taken to apply to C++11 as well. Which I guess would mean that if in the future `+v` no longer gets treated as a null pointer constant, it gets rejected in C++11 mode as well as C++14 mode.

Comment: You mean I can't use `'-'-'-'` as a null pointer constant anymore?

Comment: @hvd: There's some question whether the DR applies to C++11. http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html says: "Issues with DR, accepted, DRWP, and WP status are NOT part of the International Standard for C++." I submitted a gcc bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80648