# Which Clang warning is equivalent to Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant from GCC?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, compiler-warnings, nullptr

Our project uses C++11/14, and we want to use `nullptr` instead of `0` or `NULL` with pointers, even when `0` (as an integer literal) is allowed.

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr1 = nullptr; // #1
    int *ptr2 = 0;       // #2
}
```

If I compile with GCC (5.3.0) and the flag `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` it warnings in `#2`, but I can't find a similar flag in Clang. If I compile the code with Clang (3.7.1) and the flag `-Weverything`, I don't get any warning about `#2`.

So, is there any way to get a similar warning for this in Clang?

Comment: It's even worse than that. In C++ you're allowed to use any integer constant expression evaluating to zero, not just a literal... e.g. `!!!!!1`.

Comment: @6502 I think that was the behavior in C++98, but C++14 seems to change that. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33656869/2484624). If I understand correctly, `!!!!!1` is an integral constant expression (that evaluates to `false`) and not an integer literal.

Comment: IIRC clang actually comes with a tool to automatically replace old null pointer constants with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang doesn't support these kind of warnings (i.e., there's no `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant` equivalent in Clang). You can see it your self if you add `-Weverything` option (mind do it only for testing), which enables all Clang's warnings.

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97589e01baf4629e)

Comment: This is no longer true.

Answer (score 8):

clang has this warning as of 5.0; I added it [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/rGd7ba86b6bf54740dd4007e65a927151cb9f510b4).

Answer (score 1):

Use `-Wzero-as-null-pointer-constant`.

- Available at least since clang10 (around 2017).
- Same as gcc flag.

so bad it is not enabled by default by `-Wall -Wextra`...